# How to create version of prod build with aot using angular 4

Tags: angular

Anyone can tell me how to create versioning of prod build with aot  using angular 4 because i want to refresh or purge the browser cache on every build

Thanks

Comment: are you using the cli?

Answer (score 1):

You can create from below command.

```
ng build --prod -aot true --output-hashing all
```

--output-hashing all is recommended to avoid cashing issue.

I am using same command and [my site](https://www.greatbuyz.com/) is never faced caching issue